# an inequality for the projection on the intersection of 2 subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone give an inequality, bounding the distance of a point from its projection on the intersection of two subspaces by a function of both the distances of the point from the insividual subspaces?

Comment: A trivial one: let two subspaces be $S_1$ and $S_2$ and denote the distance of a point $p$ to $S_1 \cap S_2$, $S_1$, $S_2$ as $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$, respectively. Then $d_1 \geq \max\{d_2, d_3\}$

Comment: Actually, I wanted an upper bound.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should edit your question to emphasize that an upper bound is prefered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is a point and $A$ and $B$ are subsets, all of this in a metric space, then
$$d(x,A\cap B)\ge \max\{d(x,A),d(x,B)\}$$

but I guess that what you are looking for is an upper bound.

Let $K>0$. Take the point $P(0,K)\in\Bbb R^2$ and consider, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, the lines $y=nKx$ and $y=-nKx$. Then, the distance from $P$ to any of these lines is
$$\frac{K}{\sqrt{1+n^2K^2}}$$
but the distance from $P$ to the intersection of the lines (namely, the origin) is $K$.

Roughly speaking, fixed a distance from the point to the intersection, you can make the distance from the point to each subspace arbitrarily small. Both lines, which bigger values of $n$ move closer and closer to $P$ like a pair of scissors.

To get an upper bound, I think that you need a lower bound for the angle between the subspaces.